# Is it possible to control new window position of Brave Browser?

Tags: macos, catalina

I am using Brave Browser version 1.24.86 Chromium: 90.0.4430.212 (Official Build) (x86_64) on Catalina 10.15.5

Using a large 4K display with the browser on the right side, it's quite annoying that new popup windows appear top-left.

Comment: RE: "new popup windows appear top-left" --  What type of "popup window" are you referring to?

Comment: New window generally appear slightly down & to the right of existing windows… until you run out of space at bottom right; after which they will jump high left so the pattern can start over. I doubt you can fight that.

Comment: This is description of the problem. What is desired (alternative) outcome? What does mean 'control'? You can nicely 'control' window by dragging it, but obviously this is not what you are looking for. So what is it? If you want to open new page in same location as original browser window have you considered new tab instead of new window?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit of an over-engineered solution, but you could use an app like Keyboard Maestro (or something else similar). Create a macro that will open a new window at a certain position on the screen. Then, in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts change the "New Window" menu item to a different keyboard shortcut and set your other macro to trigger with ⌘N. This way, you don't have to change your behavior at all, but a new Brave window will open exactly where you want it. I'm sure there is other window management software that will do something similar.